# Matlab receiving no keyboard input

Tags: matlab

From time to time in Matlab, the editor suddenly does not receive my keyboard input. When I restart Matlab everything turns back to normal.

Weirdly, however, in the no-input-receiving state Matlab does not recognize any input besides cmd+q (quitting the application).

What is wrong? Do I enter any weird modes?

Comment: You should probably report this to the MathWorks. Could be something with your OS, or specific to your MATLAB installation, but I've never seen this in 20 years of using MATLAB.

Comment: Maybe the Matlab is executing something (busy)? Do you see input prompt `>>` when you can't input?